# The start timestamp is non zero-when remuxing using libavformat

Tags: ffmpeg, sdl, video-processing, libavformat

I'm remuxing a live rtmp stream using libavformat's sample [remuxing.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/master/doc/examples/remuxing.c) my code is almost identical to that sample, but it also decodes the audio and video in order to render a preview using SDL, that works great.

My application has a a button to start recording, and whenever the user presses it, the main loop will remux to a file, in a typical situation a user will wait a couple of seconds before initiating a recording, that is where the problems arise, the resulting video has non-zero start time. (I don't see these problems if I manually initiate the recording right after opening the input stream)

e.g.
The user waits 5 seconds before starting a recording, then records for 5 seconds: The reported duration is ~5s, while the start timestamp is at ~9s. VLC fails to display the duration/position properly, but it works fine in other players.

Here's an example of my main loop

```
while (1) {
    ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt);

    //decode and preview
    //set pts, dts and duration
    //...

    if(ost->record){
        //remux
        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error muxing packet\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    av_packet_unref(&pkt);
}
```

I have tried setting mux_ts_offset of the input stream, but it didn't help.

Comment: Probably related to keyframe interval used in original video (e.g. every 10 seconds). It should be possible to insert new keyframe at the beginning and recode video fragment till next keyframe (there *may* be simplier ways, but it depends on actual video codec used).

Comment: Not sure it's related, the offset is relative to the time elapsed after opening input, so for example, if I run the application and wait for 5 minutes the offset will be 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The tps you get is relative to the moment you connected to the stream. When you start recording you, memorize the tps and dps of the first packet, and shift everything by that offset.

```
first_packet = true;
while (1) {
    ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt);

    //decode and preview
    //set pts, dts and duration
    //...

    if(ost->record){

        if (first_packet) { // memorize the tps and dps of the first recorded packet
            start_pts = pkt.pts;
            start_dts = pkt.dts;
            first_packet = false;
        }

        // apply offset
        pkt.pts = pkt.pts - start_pts;
        pkt.dts = pkt.dts - start_dts;

        //remux
        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error muxing packet\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    av_packet_unref(&pkt);
}
```